Como resto numeros negativos en Python?
estoy aprendiendo Python y practicando en la pagina de exercism, pero no logro restar números negativos, algo de mi codigo.
operations_accepted = ["plus","divided","minus","multiplied"]
lista = [word for word in question.rstrip('?').split()]
operations = [word for word in lista if word in operations_accepted]
numeros = [int(word) for word in lista if word.isdigit() or word[0] == '-']
result1 = numeros[0]
while True:
    if not operations:
        break
    for i in operations:
        if i == 'plus': 
            result = numeros[0] + numeros[1]
        elif i == 'divided':
            result = numeros[0] / numeros[1]
        elif i == 'minus':
            result = (abs(numeros[1]) - abs(numeros[0]))
        elif i == 'multiplied':
            result = numeros[0] * numeros[1] 
        operations.remove(i)
        numeros.pop(0)
        numeros.pop(0)
        print('numeros despues de eliminar los dos elementos: ',numeros)
        numeros.insert(0,result)
        result1 = result
        result = 0
        
return result1

print(answer('What -1 minus -10?'))
las demas operaciones me funcionan pero la resta me da resultados inesperados, he intentado varias cosas como poner la resta en parentesis, invertir el orden de la resta y usar abs pero no encuentro como restar apropiadamente los numeros negativos. Muchas gracias.

Y por qué usas abs ???

Entonces da algún ejemplo de 2 números y cuáles es el resultado que esperas. Eso no sería un problema de programación, sino de matemática.

A ver..., -1 "minus" -10 -> (-1) - (-10) = -1 + 10 = 9... Como te comentan, no uses abs (valor absoluto), eso convierte la operación en 1 - 10..., simplemente result = numeros[0] - numeros[1] te da el resultado matemáticamente correcto. Por cierto, la resta no es conmutativa, invertir el orden de los operandos es mala idea...

@FJSevilla a menos que hagas - numeros[1] + números[0]

@Mateo claro, pero ahí simplemente se está convirtiendo la resta en suma usando la inversión aditiva (d = a - b => d = a + (-b), que es lo que en esencia es la resta). Luego puedes cambiar el orden de los operandos ya que obviamente la adición es conmutativa en el anillo de los enteros.

En todos los lenguajes de programación las operaciones aritméticas se realizan correctamente para cualquier combinación de signos de los operandos. Puedes sumar, restar, dividir y multiplicar sin importar los signos; el resultado será correcto aritméticamente.

Gracias @FJSevilla (-1) - (-10) = -1 + 10 = 9 esto me estaba pasando y no habia interiorizado que python estaba haciendo esto, y en pyhton tutor tampoco lo habia podido visualizar. aunque para que me diera el resultado correcto me toco numeros[0] - abs(numeros[1]), de las otras formas no me daba.

numeros[0] - abs(numeros[1]) no da el resultado matemáticamente correcto, no si -1 "minus" -10 se debe interpretar como (-1) - (-10). Python no está actuando de forma extraña, el resultado matemáticamente correcto de eso es 9, numeros[0] - abs(numeros[1]) da como resultado -11 y eso no es correcto...

Solo debes aplicar el modulo abs() al segundo numero:
result =  num1 - abs(num2)

código completo:
question = 'What is -15 minus -10?'
operations_accepted = ["plus", "divided", "minus", "multiplied"]
lista = [word for word in question.rstrip('?').split()]
operations = [word for word in lista if word in operations_accepted]
numeros = [int(word) for word in lista if word.isdigit() or word[0] == '-']

operacion = operations[0]
num1, num2 = numeros
 
if operacion == "plus":
     num1 + num2
elif operacion == "minus":
    result =  num1 - abs(num2)
elif operacion == "multiplied":
    result = num1 * num2
elif operacion == "divided":
    if num2 == 0:
        result =  "Can NOT be divided by 0"
    result = num1 / num2
else:
    result = "Invalid operation"

print(result)



10 - abs(-1) es lo mismo que 10 - 1 = 9, pero 10 - -1 = 11. Paradojas de la programación, misterios de las informática, ¿por qué no habrán inventado algo como la depuración?

Exacto  muchas gracias eso me funcionó.

Simplemente hazlo tal y como lo has hecho en los otros casos.
Modifica la línea
result = (abs(numeros[1]) - abs(numeros[0]))

por
result = numeros[0] - numeros[1]

De todas formas, he creado otro código más sencillo para mejorar el tuyo:
import re

numbers=re.findall("-?[0-9]+", question)  # Encontramos todos los números
operations=re.findall("|".join(operations_accepted), question)  # Encontramos todas las operaciones

switch = {"plus": "+", "minus": "-", "divided": "/", "multiplied": "*"}
sentence=""
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    sentence+=numbers[i]  # Añadimos el número al enunciado
    if i<len(operations):
        sentence+=" "+switch[operations[i]]+" "  # Añadimos la operación al enunciado

print(eval(sentence))  # Convertimos el string en una expresión


Muchas gracias @Daniel ese código ya esta a otro nivel jeje todavía me falta para entenderlo jejeje.
